# Theme Checker Text Domain

Tags: theme-development, themes, textdomain

`$output .= '<li class="recentcomments">' . sprintf(_x('%1$s %2$s - %3$s %4$s', 'thst'),  get_avatar( $comment, 48 ), (...);`

This is my line of code and Wordpress Theme Checker tells me "Text domain problems. You have not included a text domain!" I have included one though, as you can see. What could be the problem here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`_x()`](http://queryposts.com/function/_x/) is for string with a context. So your second argument is just the context, and there is no text domain.

Suggestion:

```
$string = _x( 
'%1$s %2$s - %3$s %4$s',                # string to translate
'recent comments 1 = gravatar, 2 = … ', # context for translators
'thst'                                  # text domain
);

$visible = sprintf( $string, get_avatar( $comment, 48 ), … );

$output .= '<li class="recentcomments">' . $visible . '</li>';
```

Explain all numbers in your context parameter.

Comment: `$output .= '<li class="recentcomments">' .  /* translators: comments widget: 1: comment author, 2: post link */ sprintf(_x('%1$s %2$s - %3$s %4$s'),  get_avatar( $comment, 48 ), '<div class="text">' . get_comment_author_link() , '<a href="' . esc_url( get_comment_link($comment->comment_ID) ) . '">' . get_the_title($comment->comment_post_ID) . '</a>', '<p class="date">' . get_comment_date('l, j F Y') . '</p></div>', 'thst') . '</li>';` Ok I got it now. the text domain needed to go at the very end since the other things in the middle are numbers. Thanks!

Comment: No, use a context parameter and a text domain as explained in my answer.